# I can't fetch the product from the MongoDB using react native nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, express

I have an index file in which there is an API for fetching a product from the database with the productId.
I passed a specific productId (copied and pasted from Mongo Atlas) to the postman to test the API and it worked properly and brought the product.
Here is the postman test that you can see API brings the product.

Here is the front end fetching of the API

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
try {
  console.log(productId)
  console.log("I am in try block")
  fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/fetchtproduct/${ productId }")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(typeof (data))
        console.log(data);
        setData(data);
        console.log(data.name)
      })
}
catch (error) {

  console.log("couldn't fetch data from your API Sooraj!")
  console.log(error);
}}, [])
```

**And here is the API itself**

```
router.get('/fetchtproduct/:id', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const product = await products.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)) //find(); 
    res.send(product)
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(442).send(error);
    console.log("Could not get product");
}})
```

I have already tried findOne, findById, find, JSON.strinigify()
Please help me get out of this problem. I have wasted much time finding errors.

The error it shows is

```
Unidentified Token '<' 
JSON Parse Error
```

And sometimes it shows null object like this

```
 62fd0148877cab7bc5011753
 LOG  []
 LOG  62fd0148877cab7bc5011753
 LOG  I am in try block
 LOG  object
 LOG  {}
 LOG  62fd0148877cab7bc5011753
 LOG  {}
 LOG  undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi buddy just change double quotes in fetch into ``

Like

```
 try {
  console.log(productId)
  console.log("I am in try block")
  fetch(`http://10.0.2.2:3000/fetchtproduct/${productId}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(typeof (data))
        console.log(data);
        setData(data);
        console.log(data.name)
      })
}
catch (error) {

  console.log("couldn't fetch data from your API Sooraj!")
  console.log(error);
}}, [])
```

Comment: I have already tried it. This changes nothing and that's why I used double quoted "url"

Comment: I think you need verify api endpoints first

Comment: Hey Thank you very much, it worked.
I thought you suggested single quotes but it was backticks and it worked well. 
The fetch query works within backticks